# Why zipaligning after the signing-process?

Tags: android, sign, android-build, zipalign

I recently asked myself why in android we have to **first sign** and **then zipalign** the apk. I searched for some background information, how those processes are technically working in detail. I'm still a little bit unhappy, cause those description do not really technically explain why this sequence is necessary.

But lets start from the beginning:

I know the fact that in the apk-build-process following order is necessary

1. a lot of prior steps...
2. creating the apk-file
3. **signing** the apk-file (modifies apk)
4. **zipaligning** the apk-file (modifies apk)

I found some information here:
[zipalign](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html)

So it is clear that zipalign will align internals to 4-byte-boundaries, so that all can be loaded with mmap.
It seems that a Signing- process would destroy this alignment. Therefore zipaligning has to be called at the end of the process after signing.

**But why is it possible to make a re-aligning of the apk-content, without destroying the signature of the apk!?**
the apk gets modified and the signature should not be valid after a modified apk, i thought...

Maybe someone has more technically background information than I did found here:
[Signing your application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Thanks, if anyone has some helpful, more technically detailed information.
Luke

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's related to a **package post processing**, rather than to **programming**.

Comment: I am not certain, but I believe that the signature is based on the logical contents of the APK, not their physical placement within the ZIP archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digital signature of the APK is performed by hashing the APK components. As such, you are protecting the contents of the individual files, and not their position in memory. In other words, the APK contents are signed, but not the APK itself as a single file. As you correctly state, zipalign is merely padding the files in the APK so they start on an aligned boundary, to mmap(2) more efficiently (and be able to discard files easily). The contents, however, do not change, and therefore the signature is not violated.

Comment: Your answer would perfectly explain the fact, why this order is necessary. I'm quite sure, that those paddy-byte inside the apk are ignored for signing.Glad if you could provide a link to your description of signing. Tanks

Comment: You are correct that the bytes are ignored - again , the signatures are on a per-file basis (Each file has a SHA1 value - you can look at the MANIFEST files). As for the link - this is from a book on Android Internals by Jonathan Levin, which details the exact process (it's a book, though, not a website). We're not sure SO permits links or endorsements, however - so we suggest Google here, and mention this only as a direct answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems to be pretty interesting this book, would appreciate if google would provide more detailed info's too. Mostly google provides docs in high quality.